# C++/CLI I need to improve code

Tags: datagridview, c++-cli

I have code written here, that works but need desperately to improve.

```
//////////////////////Split into sentence/////////////////////////
String^ text = textBox1->Text;
cli::array<String^>^ sentence = text->Split('.', '?', '!');
for (int i = 0; i < sentence->Length; ++i) {
    datagridview->Rows->Add();
    datagridview->Rows[i]->Cells[1]->Value = i + 1;
    datagridview->Rows[i]->Cells[3]->Value = sentence[i];   
}
//////////////////////Split into words/////////////////////////
cli::array<String^>^ word = text->Split(' ');
for (int ii = 0; ii < word->Length; ++ii) {
    datagridview->Rows[ii]->Cells[4]->Value = ii + 1;
    datagridview->Rows[ii]->Cells[5]->Value = word[ii];
    datagridview->Rows->Add();
}
```

In code text is entered and being split sentences and words. In picture below you will see my code output:
[image: Datagridview]

As you see sentence length isn't working.

I want output will be similar to a picture below.
[image: How out put should look]

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: Input data is a textbox with  "This is sentece one. Second sentece." text.

Comment: Do not ignore the return value of datagridview->Rows->Add().  It returns a reference to the added row.  You want to use that, indexing the rows like you do now is a gross bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually populating your sentence length cells (column 2) in your code so that's why nothing is appearing there.

You need something along these lines:

```
String^ text = textBox1->Text;
cli::array<String^>^ sentences = text->Split('.', '?', '!');
for each (String^ sentence in sentences) {   
    cli::array<String^>^ words = sentence->Split(' ');
    for each (String^ word in words) {
        int rowIndex = datagridview->Rows->Add();
        datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[1]->Value = i + 1;
        datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[2]->Value = sentence->Length; // This is the line you're missing
        datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[3]->Value = sentence;   
        datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[4]->Value = ii + 1;
        datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[5]->Value = word;
    }    
}
```

Edit - try this then:

```
String^ text = textBox1->Text;
cli::array<String^>^ sentences = text->Split('.', '?', '!');
for (int sentenceIndex = 0; sentenceIndex < sentences->Length; ++sentenceIndex) {   
    String^ sentence = sentences[sentenceIndex];
    cli::array<String^>^ words = sentence->Split(' ');
    for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < words->Length; ++wordIndex) {   
        int rowIndex = datagridview->Rows->Add();
        datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[1]->Value = sentenceIndex + 1;
        datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[2]->Value = sentence->Length; // This is the line you're missing
        datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[3]->Value = sentence;   
        datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[4]->Value = wordIndex + 1;
        datagridview->Rows[rowIndex]->Cells[5]->Value = words[wordIndex];;
    }    
}
```

Comment: I used your code example work really well, but still there is some glitches [link](https://imgur.com/m2tn02l) \.